# Debugging build.gradle.kts for Gradle Wrapper 4.7 build from IntelliJ 2018.1.4

Tags: debugging, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to debug a `build.gradle.kts` for a Gradle Wrapper 4.7 Kotlin DSL build in IntelliJ 2018.1.4 to.

I ran:

```
./gradlew clean`
./gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon
```

Gradle waited for a debugger to attach.

I added breakpoints throughout my `build.gradle.kts`.

I created a Remote debug config and started it.

The build ran and finished without ever breaking on any breakpoint.

I also tried debugging from the right-click menu of `Tasks/build/build` in my IntelliJ Gradle tool window, but that also just ran the task and never stopped on any breakpoint.

How can I debug `build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: If you have found an answer, please tell me =/